# Vscode highlighting No longer working after switch statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After a switch statement my Vscode highlighting has stopped working and all the text has gone the same colour and no matter how I rewrite the code it won't fix it

(This code is for a unity project)
The code highlighting still works in other IDE's like Rider however I want to use Vscode as its Intellicode is far better)

```
Vector2Int neighbour = currentCell;
            
            switch (rnDir[i])
            {
                case Direction.Up:
                    neighbour.y++;
                    break;
                case Direction.Down:
                    neighbour.y--;
                    break;
                case Direction.Right:
                    neighbour.x++;
                    break;
                case Direction.Left:
                    neighbour.x--;
                    break;

            }

            if (IsCellValid(neighbour.x, neighbour.y))return neighbour;
        }

        return currentCell;
```

Also some of the syntax highlighting still works like the ends of brackets it is just after the .Up on the first line of the switch statement

I have tried rewriting the switch statement but that has not done anything to fix the highlighting in the switch statement or after it

I was expecting the syntax highlighting to continue as it was in all the lines before it have.

Comment: well code shown has 2 end braces and only 1 open.. so... who knows

Comment: Do Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F to format code then see which function , if statement is missing a bracket

Comment: Does the code compile in Unity?